# How to re-size inputs for a <%= form_for %> form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

If I were trying to decrease the width of the "email" and "password" forms :

```
    <div id="signin">
    <h1>Sign in</h1>

    <%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
      </div>
     <% end %>
```

...and place them in my navbar at the upper right, how would the CSS look?

Why would....

```
    #signin #field.text_field {

    width:20px;

    }
```

...not work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' `.text_field` method will generate an `input` tag in your HTML, so you need to target that `input` tag instead. Also, you should be using `.field`, not `#field`, since it's a class, not an id.

```
#signin .field input {
  width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Dylan, if I wanted to position it left to right in my toolbar ---> Email Form then Password Form, how could I manipulate my code for each "field" class (above)?

Comment: You could simply get rid of the wrapping `divs` around each pair of labels/fields, and then get rid of the `<br/>` tags, and everything would display in a single line.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't even realize that since I was trying to convert a regular sign in form with breaks. TY again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `field` is defined as class but not an id.

`#signin .field.text_field { width: 20px; }`

or

I think you can modify your line 6 to

`<%= f.text_field :email, :size => 10 %>`